# Responsive design. Div not scaling, font size not changing

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem making a responsive web page. (Note in actual page I use % for font sizes, but for used pt size for the stripped test version for a visual aid.)

I included the viewport meta and tried a few versions including this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-  
scalable=no">
```

and this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

And I've tried "@media only screen" on the below as well.

Here is the css of the stripped version... and I've tried many, many variation:

```
*.div-top-nav {
    width: 773px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #6f881d;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
       -khtml-border-radius: 8px;
       border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 1px #FFFFFF;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 1px #FFFFFF;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 1px #FFFFFF;  
   font-size: 40pt;
}


@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    *.div-top-nav {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 748px !important;
    float: none  !important;    
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    font-size: 20pt;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    *.div-top-nav {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 440px !important;
    float: none  !important;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    font-size: 20pt;
    }
}
```

**Update: PROBLEM**

I expect the div to scale and font size to change with screen size but it is not behaving that way.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: In addition to what Ejay said, your question title should succinctly state what your problem is, not "Need advice for."  Also, "it is just not work" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Why is it NOT working????

Comment: why do you have the star (*) before `.div-top-nav`?

Comment: you should use mysqli rather than myql php db functions.  Also, don't forget to check permissions on the folder if you can't write to it.  Does that answer your question?  wait what was it?

Comment: Nobody knows what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay let me be more specific.I don't understand why the div is not scaling in the smaller screens and the font is also not re-sizing. Is there an error in the css or meta? Or is something missing?

Comment: Are you familiar with JSFiddle? Also, consider including your HTML?

Comment: I guess the * is "old school" css... I've been using css since I started in 1999 and was taught to do it that way, and never ever has issues either... I removed the * before .div-top-nav and still it is not scaling the div or re-sizing the font. Truly I must be missing something.

And by the way, I'm asking for help, not fresh smarty comments. That doesn't impress me.

Comment: Is JSFiddle required for @media css to work? I've used it for other things.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `device-width` for desktop. Your media-queries should work on actual devices but not when you resize the browser.

`device-width` refers to the display's width whereas `width` is the width of the window itself. So in your case you should use:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .... etc
```

Comment: Thank you. I was certain I had an error. Changing the device-width to width did the trick. I appreciate it and have a great weekend.